# Can't remap Ctrl+W to the F2 key in autohotkey

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

My mind is blown; it seems like the easiest thing but:

`w::F2` works

`^w::F2` doesn't work no matter what

If something was mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, it doesn't perform it, but it doesn't *press* <kbd>F2</kbd> either.

Answer (score 2):

From the help file documentation this should work...
but it's not here, either.
The documentation says "AutoHotkey's remapping feature described below is generally not as pure and effective as ...." so it is expected that the direct remapping doesn't always work.

Use this instead

```
^w::Send,{F2}
```